# Any references on supercomplex/surcomplex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, surreal-numbers, hypercomplex-numbers

I know many text in surreal numbers have went over them but I can't seem to find anything that goes into great detail beyond a small section on them. For instance, in Foundation of Analysis over Surreal Number Fields the section on them was fairly small and not much to my liking. Is there anything that explains them in good detail?

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Noo}{\mathbf{No}}$I don't think any analog is known in surcomplex numbers $\Noo[i]$ to the property

"if $L < R$ are sets of surreals, then there is a simplest surreal $x$ such that $L < x < R$"

(except if one deals seperately with projections in $\Noo$ and $\Noo.i$)

No one (to my knowledge) has found a nice surcomplex exponential, nor is there a nice integration theory for surcomplex numbers (let alone a nice surcomplex analysis).

---

All these notions could be worked out in surreals in order to define them for surcomplex numbers, but so far $\Noo$ has remained quite selfish in what it offers to its algebraic closure.

As a result, surcomplex numbers seem like "just" the bland universal algebraically closed field of caracteristic zero with an interesting real closed subfield.
So maybe there are few texts on them because everybody's still stuck with surreals...

---

(about your question, I am not sure I understand it: what does "equivalent means"?)

Comment: Thanks, man. What do you mean by projections? Also by equivalent I mean are the supercomplex numbers isomorphic to the surreals?

Comment: @ZalTukhara: Projections are maps $\pi_1: (a +bi) \mapsto a$ and $\pi_2: (a+bi) \mapsto b$, similar to real and imaginary part for the regular complex field. Noah Schweber answered your question in his post; do you know how to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are not isomorphic?

Comment: Nevermind then. I read a source, or could have sworn I read a source that said surreals and surcomplex numbers are isomorphic but I knew it sounded fishy on first read. Yes, I can tell as to how they are not and how it follows into the surreals. Just needed a confirmation that $\textbf No[i] \not \cong \textbf No$ which I have now.

Answer (score 2):

Re: your last question, certainly not, for exactly the same reason that $\mathbb{R}\not\cong\mathbb{C}$: the surreal numbers have no square root of $-1$.